# Linux java wrapper and installer

Tags: java, installation, wrapper

I have a java app that i want to release it for all of platforms. i tried most of installers and wrapper like install4j , launch4j , Excelsior JET and ...

I found best solution for windows and mac in Advanced Installer. it build a native launcher and installer for windows and mac. also it can download jre from custom source and install it if jre not present.

so im looking for similar one for linux with this features:

. wrap java

. download jre if not present from custom source

. make gui installer

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [IzPack](http://izpack.org/), especially [its features](http://izpack.org/features/).

Sources at https://github.com/izpack/izpack

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer, I am the author of InstallBuilder) [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) can create launchers for Linux, Windows and Mac and can create a GUI installer. However, it cannot download the JRE if not present.

Comment: As of Nov 2015 InstallBuilder has no free options.

Comment: We have free licenses for open source projects, just ping us. If you are a small business we also have discounts, we know first hand how hard is to bootstrap a business

Comment: @DanielLopez what about students ?

Comment: @buddhi741 We can give you a free license, please write to us and explain your project and we will figure something out :)

Comment: im willing to pay something but i have to budget it in ill hit you up after asking the supervisor