# Cross platform installer/wrapper for Java app - maven build

Tags: java, maven, installation, cross-platform

As of November 2016 state, I am looking for a way to distribute Java app, as self-contained app to run on Windows/Mac OS/Linux flavor. That is to bundle it with JRE.

I have looked at http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/, but it is installer for windows only.

The ideal solution would be to have it as a step of Maven build.

Looked at old [Linux java wrapper and installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264266/linux-java-wrapper-and-installer)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html). It can build crossplatform installers

Answer (score 1):

You may use maven-shaded-plugin in combination with [launch4j-maven-plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin)

[here](http://www.hascode.com/2012/08/creating-a-windows-executable-from-a-jar-using-maven/) is good example  of this (windows)